# How to pass parameter from views to formset Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to pass parameter from views.py to formset in forms.py  Django ? 
My setup: Django 2.0.7, Python 3.6.5

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by overriding the `get_form_kwargs` method in Class Based View. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) is a small description in the documentation and [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_form_kwargs) you can find the source code.

What `get_form_kwargs` does is passing a dictionary of keywords arguments to `__init__` in a form. So you have to change your code in two places - views.py and forms.py.

The example:

**views.py**

```
class CreatePost(generic.CreateView):
    # SOMETHING HERE

    def get_from_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({"user", self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # SOMETHING HERE

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields["group"].queryset = models.Group.object.filter(members = user)
```

What I am doing in the code above is passing the user from views to forms and then getting the queryset of the groups to which user belongs to (in Group model there is members ManyToManyField).

Someone posted also another example [here](https://gist.github.com/vero4karu/ec0f82bb3d302961503d).